# Azure DataFactory: Start / End time of schedule Pipelines

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have a pipelines in Azure DataFactory which is scheduled to run hourly.
Since every schedule task will have start time and end time (e.g. 1am - 2am) to copy files within this interval. I would like to know if old task overrun like finishing at 2:15am, what will be behaviour of next task?
(a) running task with start time and end time 2am-4am
(b) running task with start time and end time 3am-4am

My aim is to make sure no missing copying files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tested this in my ADF.

**Conclusion:**
The previous pipeline's status won't affect the next task start time. So in your case, if you the previous pipeline started at 1am and finished at  2:15am, your next task will still start at  2am.

My test:
I create a Schedule trigger which runs every 3 min. My pipeline runs about 6 min.

[image]

Monitor pipeline runs and trigger runs:
[image]

[image]

My first task ends at 3/4/21, 3:32:41 PM, and the next task starts at 3/4/21, 3:30:00 PM. So if old task overrun, it won't affect the next task start time.